# Solutions to $(4x^2+\frac{16}3x)^{\sqrt {3-x}}=(4x^2+\frac{16}3x)^{\sqrt {2x+11}-\sqrt{x+2}}$

Tags: exponentiation, quadratics

$$(4x^2+\frac{16}3x)^{\sqrt {3-x}}=(4x^2+\frac{16}3x)^{\sqrt {2x+11}-\sqrt{x+2}}$$

I found the solutions to be $0, -\frac32, -1, -\frac43$

I can't figure out why any of those wouldn't work, but my textbook apparently only sees $-\frac43$ as valid...

Namely, the question asks for the sum of all the answers, and the correct answer is "$-\frac43$"

So am I wrong? If so, where? Am I missing a solution? Thanks.

Apparently $1/6$ is a solution as well... How do you get this? I still don't get their solution...

Comment: To get x=1/6 note that when 4x^2+(16/3)x=1, it does not matter what exponent we raise each side of the original equation to because 1^a where a is real is always just 1.

Comment: I assume that the textbook is wrong then, because all of the solutions obviously don't add up to $-4/3$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution might arise because the base is $0$ and it is raised to a nonnegative power. Solving $4x^2+\frac{16}3x=0$ yields $x\in\{0,-4/3\}$. Both of these work, once you have checked that the make the exponents nonnegative real.

So now assume $x$ is a solution that does not make the base $0$. $x$ might be such that it makes the base $\pm1$. We'll need to treat this separately as well for what comes next. Solving $4x^2+\frac{16}3x=1$ yields $x\in\{1/6,-3/2\}$. Both of these solutions are valid, since they make each side $1^{\text{real}}$.

Solving $4x^2+\frac{16}3x=-1$ yields $x=-\frac{2}{3}\pm\frac{\sqrt{7}}{6}$. These don't work out as solutions though, because at least on the left side, you have $(-1)^{\text{non-integer}}$.

OK, now ruling out any solutions $x$ that make the base $0$ or $\pm1$:
$$\begin{align}
(4x^2+\frac{16}3x)^{\sqrt {3-x}}&=(4x^2+\frac{16}3x)^{\sqrt {2x+11}-\sqrt{x+2}}\\
\implies \left|4x^2+\frac{16}3x\right|^{\sqrt {3-x}}&=\left|4x^2+\frac{16}3x\right|^{\sqrt {2x+11}-\sqrt{x+2}}\\
\end{align}$$
Applying the logarithm base $\left|4x^2+\frac{16}3x\right|$ is valid, since this base is positive but not $1$:
$$\begin{align}
{\sqrt {3-x}}&={\sqrt {2x+11}-\sqrt{x+2}}\\
\implies3-x&=2x+11-2\sqrt{(2x+11)(x+2)}+x+2\\
\implies-4x-10&=-2\sqrt{(2x+11)(x+2)}\\
\implies2x+5&=\sqrt{(2x+11)(x+2)}\\
\implies4x^2+20x+25&=2x^2+15x+22\\
\implies2x^2+5x+3&=0\\
\implies(2x+3)(x+1)&=0\\
\end{align}$$
So potentially, $-1$ and $-3/2$ are more solutions. Actually, we already established $-3/2$ is a solution. Some of the implications that led here were only one-way, so we should check $x=-1$. $x=-1$ makes the equation read $(-4/3)^2=(-4/3)^{3-1}$, which is true depending on how raising negative numbers to powers is defined. And this may be an issue. You are probably thinking that raising a negative number to the 2nd power just means multiply the base by itself. But generally, raising a negative number to a real power gives a nonreal result, and if you want raising to the 2nd power to give results that are "close" to the result from raising to the $1.9$th power, say, then you don't define raising to the 2nd power as doubled multiplication. For this reason, many computer systems behave this way and would define $(-4/3)^2$ as $\exp(2\ln(-4/3))$, where $\ln(-4/3)$ is defined using an (arbitrary) choice of branch of the logarithm that extends to the negative reals.

Because of the arbitrary choice that is made to do this, many other systems simply declare raising any negative number to *any* power to be undefined, even when the power is an integer. If that were the system in play, then $-1$ is not a valid solution, since both sides of the equation would be undefined.

So either the sum of solutions is $0-\frac43+\frac16-\frac32=-\frac{8}{3}$ (if you don't count $-1$) or $0-\frac43+\frac16-\frac32-1=-\frac{11}{3}$ (if you do).

Comment: Have I made some kind of error? Would the downvoters explain? For a second I omitted the base $1$ possibility. Perhaps the current edited version addresses the concerns?

Comment: Either way, those who made this exercise got it wrong. I see. Thank you for taking the time to write all that out :)

Answer (score 2):

$x = \frac 16$ is one of the solutions to $ 4x^2-\frac {16}{3}x = 1$

Three ways to establish equality.

1) $4x^2 + \frac{16}{3} x = 0$ whose roots sum to $-\frac 43 $

2)  $4x^2 + \frac{16}{3} x = 1$ whose roots also sum to $-\frac 43 $

3) $\sqrt{3-x} = \sqrt{2x+11}- \sqrt{x+2}$ is equivalent to $x^2+\frac 52 x + \frac 32 = 0 $  whose roots sum to $-\frac 52 $

Comment: For whatever reason, $\frac52$ is given as a possible answer yet it is not "correct". Am I right in assuming that this is probably just a case of bad exercise making?

Comment: No the third equation has negative delta and has not root and $\frac{5}{2}$ is not true.

Comment: I meant $-\frac52$, sorry

Comment: actually I think the book may be correct ( especially if it asks for the sum of the distinct solutions) the solution at $x=-1$ is not in the domain ( negative number to irrational power )  and the solutions at $x=-\frac 32$ are not distinct - the only thing that bothers me is $x=-\frac 43 $ seems to be not counted also, When I graph the original function it seems to have an assymptote here.

Comment: Maybe both solutions to 1) are not counted. And maybe they only counted the solutions within the domain of the equation for 2) and 3) (you know without counting the solution -3/2 twice). Though I think 0 being base is perfectly okay when being raised to positive power.